# Python implementation of a blind signature scheme which doesn't involve RSA

Tags: implementation, blind-signature

RSA seems a bit creepy after the Snowden revelations and i'm looking for a simple python based blind signature library to fiddle around with. So far i've been unable to find anything. What am i missing?

Comment: What are exactly your concerns about RSA after the Snowden revelations? I mean the cryptosystem, not the company.

Comment: Generating good enough primes is the deal-breaker for me..

Comment: @user37203: Really if you don't trust prime number generation !
Otherwise the reference in blind signature was introduced in the early $90^{ies}$ by David Chaum, that you can search over the web.
However this is without some controversies as this paper claims it: https://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/temp/electronic.cash/basic.papers.electronic.cash/Blind%20signatures%20Bland.pdf

Comment: All the blind signature schemes i have found use RSA, and come as a part of a pretty big package - they depend on too many external things. I'm really looking for a small library such as [ed25519-python](https://github.com/warner/python-ed25519)

Comment: @user37203: What do you mean with "Generating good enough primes ....."? Together with your last post, do you mean that the prime number generation part of a big package is  in practice fairly troublesome to check whether it's free of security problems (and impossible if the package is binary)? If so, I have had the same concern and implemented in some 50 lines of Python Maurer's algorithm (see HAC p.153) of generation of random provable (in contrast to highly probable) primes, available at http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/

Comment: RSA based blind signatures are relatively easy to understand and IMO have less room for mistakes than group based blind signatures. If you want simpler padding, use FDH instead of PSS. I trust them significantly more, the only major downside is performance. One pitfall is that you should make sure that GCD(m, N) = 1, not only GCD(r, N) = 1.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : $\:$ Another pitfall is that you should make sure that [the public key defines a permutation](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-34961-4_25). $\;\;\;\;$